# Cambiar servidor por defecto de Alfresco SDK

Tags: java, alfresco

He bajado el SDK de Alfresco y lo he abierto en eclipse como muestra el tutorial descrito [aquí](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk)

El caso es que al instalarlo, funciona correctamente, pero lo que necesitaba es cambiar el servidor por defecto en el que arranca el propio alfresco y desplegarlo directamente en uno que tengo en local donde tengo otra aplicación alojada (que interactuará con el propio alfresco). El server que estoy usando para dicha aplicación es el Pivotal tc Server que viene por defecto en el STS de Spring. El problema es que no se donde tengo que tocar.

Answer (score 1):

Este es un buen lugar donde mirar:

```
"tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties"
```

Yo no se realmente porque me acuerdo de esto pero una vez mire este archivo en slideshare te dejo el link mas en concreto en la pagina 16:

http://es.slideshare.net/toniblyx/instalacin-de-afresco-en-espaol

Esto tambien te puede servir

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/WQS-config-single-app.html (link ingles)

Comment: @Raider no te lo dejo como comentario porque quizas cueste enterder con varios link y creo que asi te sera mas comodo, si porque cualquier motivo esto no te ayuda, me puedes dejar un comentario Saludos